# Is there a Map object with takes index and key and object? Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, encryption, hashmap

I'm trying to emulate a rotor of an enigma machine in Java.
I need an object which takes an index, a key and an object, because I unsuccessfully tried HashMaps like this:

```
private HashMap<Integer,Integer> rotorWiring = new HashMap<Integer, Integer();
private HashMap<Integer,Integer> reverseRotorWiring = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

//The "wiring" of the rotor is set from a String,
    public void setRotorWiring(String Wiring) {
    if (Wiring.length()==26) {
        for (int i=0; i<Wiring.length();i++ ) {
            char tempChar = Wiring.charAt(i);
            int valueOfChar = (int)tempChar-64; 
            if (valueOfChar<=26){
                this.rotorWiring.put(i+1,valueOfChar);
                this.reverseRotorWiring.put(valueOfChar,i+1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So far so good, this allows me to translate e.x. an A to an E, however, once I tried to simulate a turn of the rotor like this:

```
//It should be mentioned that I designing the program to only accept characters a to z inclusive.
public void turn() {
    for (int i=1;i<=rotorWiring.size();i++) {
        if (i!=26) {
            rotorWiring.replace(i, rotorWiring.get(i+1));
        }
        else {
            rotorWiring.replace(i, rotorWiring.get(1));
        }
    }
    for (int i=1;i<=rotorWiring.size();i++) {
        if (i!=26) {
            reverseRotorWiring.replace(i, rotorWiring.get(i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

However, I noticed that this rather simulates an offset of the internal wiring of the rotor rather than a turn...  I'm asking for a "Map"-like solutions with an index, key and object, because that would allow me to offset the index of all the keys and objects by 1, thus simulating a turn.

I am, however, open to suggestions for different solutions to this problem.

It should be mentioned that I'm a bit of a novice, and therefore appreciate rather in-depth explanations.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't know if there is a more suitable title for this question, if so, please suggest!

Comment: I am not aware of such a data structure, you would probably have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I feared as much... Would I be able to build upon an existing data structure. e.x. extending Map or ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. There doesn't exist an implementation of what you have described in JDK. However, there are more ways to achieve the storing of `Integer-String-Object`. Note that both the index and the key are unique by definition. Also, note that the index-key are tightly coupled. You might want to put a `Map` to another `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, MyObject>> map;
```

Or use a collection characteristic for indices:

```
List<Map<String, MyObject>>
```

Be careful with removing items which change the index of all the subsequent elements - replace it with `null` instead to keep the indices. Alternatively, you can create a decorator for your defined object with index/key:

```
Map<Integer, MyDecoratedObject> map;
```

Where the `MyDecoratedObject` would look like:

```
public class MyDecoratedObject {

     private final String key;      // or int index
     private final MyObject delegate;

     // Full-args constructor, getters
}
```

Finally, it's up to you to pick a way that satisfied your requirements the most.

Comment: Don't call it decorated object but pair?!

Comment: @GhostCat: In my opinion, a pair is necessarily a data-object storing only and only 2 values as a couple (ex. `Entry`). On the other hand, the usage of a decorator is unlimited - it allows to add an functionality, metadata without changing the decorated object's interface - here I mean to decorate the object with an index. OP can enlarge this decorator or add another one. I'd speak not about a pair only.

Comment: A map of maps seems to be a good suggestion, however, how would I  make a for-loop which makes a new map for each character of a string? Also I convert the characters to integers for easier processing. E.x. a=1, b=2, c=3 etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @N.Kuno: Create a new map inside each loop, fill in with entries and put itself as a value of the outer map.

Answer (score 0):

A map of maps was the solution! It was solved like this:

```
    private HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,Integer>> rotorWiring = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer,Integer>>();
    private HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,Integer>> reverseRotorWiring = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer,Integer>>();

    public void setRotorWiring(String Wiring) {
    if (Wiring.length()==26) {
        for (int i=0; i<Wiring.length();i++ ) {
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> wire = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> reverseWire = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            char tempChar = Wiring.charAt(i);
            int valueOfChar = (int)tempChar-64; 
            if (valueOfChar<=26){
                wire.put(i+1,valueOfChar);
                reverseWire.put(valueOfChar,i+1);
                rotorWiring.put(i, wire);
                reverseRotorWiring.put(i, reverseWire);
            }
        }
    }

}
```